# Can Chronicle Map use a network file share for read only data?

Tags: networking, chronicle, chronicle-map

I would like to use Chronicle Map to read a serialized map from a network file share and then process it locally.  We would have 100+ machines reading prepared data from a map - lots of iteration but never writing.  Can I just have one process create the map on a network file share and then each 'consumer' load and process the map.  Maps would be no more than 1 million keys, 1K values.  Or do we need to use the UDP / TCP replication feature?

Answer (score 0):

Network file stores don't guarantee when a update will ever be visible to a reader.  You can't open a file on one machine while that file is being modified by another machine.

You need to either replicate the data, or access the data on a smaller set of node remotely. e.g. via Engine.